# Word to describe small patches of dry earth

Tags: word-request

When children are playing football/soccer on a dry grassy ground in hot season sometimes small patches of dry earth rise while hitting the ball. What word can describe those?

> patches/scrapes/pieces of dry earth flew about?

I have tried to search the word on jnternet but cannot get any satisfactory result.

Patch of earth means an area of land.
Scrape is also showing a different meaning: a place where soil has been scraped away, especially a shallow hollow formed in the ground by a bird during a courtship display or for nesting.

Comment: _Patches_ is appropriate if you mean 'bald' spots in the grass, but these can't 'fly about'. Loose bits of earth that are thrown up by the ball could be _dust_ or _bits/fragments of soil/earth_.

Comment: Are you talking about a piece of earth like a solid chunk of earth, or dust that rises when the ball hits the earth?

Comment: @stangdon Small bits /crumbly particles. Of course the dust also rises.

Answer (score 1):

Pieces is the the best word from the ones that you have suggested. To my mind it would probably refer to pieces that are 1-2cm in size. For smaller than this, [bits](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bit) is probably the best choice, and for larger, [chunks](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chunk). If it contains bits of grass, you could also call it a [divot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divot).

Note: Scrape probably isn't the word you were thinking of: try [scrap](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrap), though I would not use this word about earth.